# geom_ribbon skips available data (sometimes)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with geom_ribbon seemingly skipping values of prediction intervals around predicted values. I already drew out observations (points; observ), predictions (line; fit) and upper/lower PIs (ribbon; lwr/upr), saved to a CSV, and am calling on that file to build these figures. I have a number of other plots calling on the same dataset that properly draw out the ribbon with data provided (see *lilg*, below); however, there are a couple that will only plot the predictions and observations, but do not include the *entire* ribbon (despite values being present).

The following is my code for the figure:

```
ggplot(allpreds, aes(year,observ))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_point(data=subset(allpreds,meadow=="bigG"))+
  geom_line(data=subset(allpreds,meadow=="bigG"), aes(year, nomosfit))+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(allpreds,meadow=="bigG"), alpha=0.1, aes(ymin = nomoslwr, ymax = nomosupr))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45,hjust=1))+
  xlab("Year")+ylab("")+
  ggtitle("bigG")+theme(plot.title=element_text(margin = ggplot2::margin(t= 10, b = -15)))+ylim(-1.3,1.3)
```

Here are functional and not-so-functional outputs. Sorry for hyperlinks rather than embedded images... not enough street cred. Note the prediction line from 2014 - 2016 but lack of accompanying ribbon (despite available data, further down):

[image]

This can be contrasted with another that is functioning (only difference in code is meadow):
[image: not-so-problematic ribbon]

Just a sliver of my data, to show you what is being called on and presence of data:
[image: datasliver]

I have poked around other geom_ribbon feeds but cannot find anything to help alleviate the issue or side-step it. Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time!
Ben

Comment: Hi Ben - can you share your dataset via posting the result of `dput(allpreds)`?  It would make it easier to debug with you.  If that's going to be too much data to post here, you can alternatively post only a subset of the data via that method.  The resulting text string can be copy-pasted to recreate the dataframe as you have it.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess at this point, but could you try `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.3, 1.3), oob = scales::squish))` instead of your current `ylim`?

Comment: teunbrand, thanks (a) for swapping out hyperlinks for images in the post and (b) for the suggestion. It's working! I have been fussing with it for a while now so thank you for the functional guess. Looking into oob, scales::squish is used to "[squish] out of bounds values into range"... but the upr/lwr ribbon values are well within y limits. Any ideas as to why this works?